# Search through kernel make menuconfig configuration menu entries

Tags: search, linux-kernel, menu

When I run make menuconfig inside /usr/src/linux directory, the kernel configuration wizard appears. How can I search through the menu entries inside the make menuconfig wizard? I've tested /, but / it appears that / searches only through the .config file. I.e. when I search for "pci dma", there are no results, however there exists an appropriate kernel menu entry to enable DMA for PCI devices.

I was able to find the text of the menu entries inside Kconfig files. The Kconfig files are located in many subdirectories of /usr/src/linux directory. Still, searching through Kconfig files doesn't give me the actual "tree" view of the option I want to find.
The command I used to find that one out:

`grep -i --directories=recurse 'kprobes' /usr/src/linux --color=always | less`

How can I search through the menu entries inside the make menuconfig wizard?

[image]

//edit: A working solution:

`find /usr/src/linux/ -name 'Kconfig' -exec egrep -i -B 1 '(tristate|bool|menu)' '{}' \; | grep -i -B 1 --color=always 'Device Drivers'`

This will show up, what kernel .config name contains the .config label specified. All I have to do now is to look for the config name inside make menuconfig (by using /).

Comment: For other readers: I just learned that, when you do a `/` search, the number next to each result is meaningful.  Type that number on the keyboard to go directly to that result.  https://web.archive.org/web/20190802182621/https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-kbuild/msg07097.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you press `/`, it says

```
Enter CONFIG_ (sub)string to search for (with or without "CONFIG_")
```

which means it's looking for the *names* of the options, not the labels of the options.

With Linux 3.3, I found your option using grep...

```
$ find . -name Kconfig -exec grep 'config.*PCI' {} + | grep DMA
./drivers/ide/Kconfig:config BLK_DEV_IDEDMA_PCI
```

And then opened the file `./drivers/ide/Kconfig` to see more information

```
config BLK_DEV_IDEDMA_PCI
    bool
    select BLK_DEV_IDEPCI
    select BLK_DEV_IDEDMA_SFF
```

Since it doesn't have a `tristate` or `bool` line like the others, that suggests it doesn't appear in the menu.

Searching in the same file for `BLK_DEV_IDEDMA_PCI`, you can see lots of entries that refer to it, e.g.

```
config BLK_DEV_AMD74XX
    tristate "AMD and nVidia IDE support"
    depends on !ARM
    select IDE_TIMINGS
    select BLK_DEV_IDEDMA_PCI
```

So it looks like you're not supposed to enable DMA explicitly: the drivers that need DMA will enable it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I've also found out that the information I need is inside Kconfig files. Check this out: find /usr/src/linux/ -iname 'Kconfig' -exec grep --color=always -i -H -A 3 -B 3 'kprobes' '{}' \; -exec echo \; | less   . To search through kernel source files for the information is a little cumbersome way though.